# Woocommerce subscription initial payment on expiry

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I have used woo-commerce subscription plugin for my products. Now client want that if a subscription is expired, a new subscription is automatically started for the same order and customer. I an using the schedule action expiry hook to proceed further.
Now when a subscription expired, below my script is used, which create a new subscription for order. But the initial payment is not working for that. Will you please look into that and help me.
This is my code after expiry hook script.

```
       /* after subscription expired */
        $subscription = wcs_get_subscription( $subscription_id );
      //  wcs_create_resubscribe_order( $subscription );
        $order = method_exists( $subscription, 'get_parent' ) ? $subscription->get_parent() : $subscription->order;
        $items = $order->get_items();
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
               $order_id     = $order->get_order_number();
               $product_name = $item->get_name();
               $product_id   = $item->get_product_id();

               /* Get variation attribute based on product ID */
                $product = new WC_Product_Variable( $product_id );
                $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
                foreach ($variations as $variation) {
                     if($variation['attributes']['attribute_velg-antall'] == 'Custom'){
                        $variationID  = $variation['variation_id'];
                        $price_args   = number_format($variation['display_price'],2);

                     }
                }
            }
               $quantity      = 1;   
               $variation_id  =  (string)$variationID;
               $variation_factory = new WC_Product_Variation($variation_id);
               $variation_obj = $variation_factory->get_variation_attributes(); 
               $price_params  = array( 'variation' => $variation_obj, 'totals' => array( 'subtotal' => $price_args*$quantity, 'total' => $price_args*$quantity, 'subtotal_tax' => 0, 'tax' => 0 ) );


               $start_date = wcs_get_datetime_utc_string( wcs_get_objects_property( $order, 'date_created' ) );
               $period     = WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_period( $variation_id );
               $interval   = WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_interval( $variation_id );
               $sub        = wcs_create_subscription( array( 'order_id' => $order_id, 'billing_period' => $period, 'billing_interval' => $interval, 'start_date' => $start_date )) ;
               $sub->add_product( wc_get_product( $product_id ), $quantity, $price_params );
               $sub->calculate_totals();
               WC_Subscriptions_Manager::activate_subscriptions_for_order($order);
```

Comment: You can't use the same payment/order for this as the gateway will not be sync anymore with woocommerce. Recurring payments renewal (or changes) need to be approved by the payment gateway on customer action exclusively. In this case a new order need to be processed by the customer anyways.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Will you please give some reference link for that, so that i am able to convince my client .

Comment: Actually I want a script which automatically resubscribed a subscription when its expire.